# Getting unhandled exception "Log entry string is too long. A string written to the event log cannot exceed 32766 characters"

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, user-controls

I am receiving an Unhandled exception Error:

> [ArgumentException: Log entry string is too long. A string written to the event log cannot exceed 32766 characters.]
>
> ####.UI.WebControls.MainControl.DealWithException(Exception e) +1212
>     ####.UI.WebControls.MainControl.CreateChildControls() +4799
>     System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +122
>     System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +49
>     System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +226
>     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7632

I am getting this error just after the **Begin PreRender** Event.

Few things about the program :

1. Program uses a custom web Control which is having an argument for specifying the usercontrol if any.
2. The whole program is contained in a user control. That is, aspx is only having a webcotrol, rest everything is in the ascx.
3. I am not using any logging mechanism, as far as i know.

please help. It will be mighty helpful to me.

Please comment if any other information is required.

Comment: Contact Intel (or whoever wrote the Intel.Sps code) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to talk to the component vendor; it's their component that's attempting to write to the event log.  Nothing we can do about it here.

Comment: but this is not a consistant problem....sometimes i get the error and sometimes i dont...the thing is that now i have commented everything out in the code behind of the user control and still it is throwing the error.. :(

Comment: Yes, precisely as I said, you will need to talk to the component vendor.  The exception is thrown in their code, the error is in their code, it's their code, their code, their code.  Contact them.